# How to call a class with this trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

My question is two-fold :

I am trying to call a Class with a Trigger upon the editing of a field value. However, that Class also has a callout, and apparently we cannot be executed when there is an uncommitted transaction.

Here :

You have uncommitted work pending... (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328873&type=1&mode=1)

So, I'm wondering if I am able to call this Class using a 'before update' setting in the trigger.

If I can do that, I would need to put the necessary code into this already existing trigger for the object :

```
trigger Trigger_ProgramContactRole on Program_Contact_Role__c (after insert, after update, before insert, before update ,after delete) {
    //Checking for the event type
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        
        //Checking for the request type
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            
            // Update Servicer on contact
            ProgramContactRoleTriggerHelper.updateServicerOnPCR(Trigger.new);
            
        }
        
        //Checking for the request type
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            
            // call deleteProgramContactRoleRecors
            ProgramContactRoleTriggerHelper.deleteProgramContactRoleRecors(Trigger.new);
            
        }
```

That would need to call this class :

```
public class UpdateContactPCRController {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static String  updateContact(String recordId){        
       
        String contactId = '';       
        
        List<Contact> contactToBeupdate = new List<Contact>();        
        
        if(String.isNotBlank(recordId)){            
            
            List<Program_Contact_Role__c> programContacList = [SELECT Id,Contact__c,Program_Name__c FROM Program_Contact_Role__c WHERE Id =:recordId AND Contact__c != null];
            contactId = programContacList[0].Contact__c;
            
            if(String.isNotBlank(contactId)){
                
                contactToBeupdate = [Select Id,Pardot_Action_Trigger__c,PCR_Register_Button_Link__c,PCR_URL_for_UI__c FROM Contact Where Id =: contactId Limit 1];                
                
                contactToBeupdate[0].Program_Contact_Role_Id__c = recordId;
            }
                        List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> programCommunicationRecs = [Select Id,Name,
                                  Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name,Receipient__c,                
                                              From Program_Communication_Recipients__c Where 
                                                           Program_Communication__r.Program__c =: programContacList[0].Program_Name__c AND 
                                                           Receipient__c =: programContacList[0].Id];                                           
                                
                
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c = String.valueOf(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c);                                                    

 pardotCallout(contactToBeupdate[0].Id);
    {

        @future(callout=true) 
        public static void pardotCallout(String contactId) {
            String returnedResponseFromPardot = Http_Utility_Pardot.pardotCreateProspect(new Set<Id> {contactId});
            // new treatment here with the returned value included DML operations.
    }

        if(contactToBeupdate.size() > 0){
            update contactToBeupdate;  
        }
        
        return 'Updated Successfully';
    }
}
```

The Pardot callout which is causing the error is coming from the last two lines of the class. ​​​​​​​

How can this be incorporated into this trigger - and only done when a field is changed ?

Thank you very much for any help you can give.

Comment: Hi, just to suggest few things, follow Salesforce recommendations regarding logicless triggers (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/success-cloud-coding-conventions/implement-frameworks-sc), you can use this framework https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework and maybe from the handler classes you can achieve what you need.

Other would be, please attach a couple of lines of the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do callouts in a trigger context, so you need to make the callout asynchronously with either a `@future` annotation in a static method or using the `Queueable` and `Database.AllowsCallouts` interfaces.

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_async_overview.htm
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex

Comment: Can I not leave the callout in the class where it is now, and just call the class with the trigger ?

Comment: You will need to finish the transaction before calling out. That is why the callout is made in an asynchronous context (after the main transaction finishes).

Comment: So is it just a matter of putting a @Future (callout-true) in front of the  "contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c..." callout line ? Or do I do it right at the beginning of the class ? If so, does the callout line need to also be placed behind the update line ? Also, should this all be a Before Update trigger ? How would you invoke that class in the trigger I have listed which labels all of the different types ? I just want to call that Class, with the recordID being set to the current record.

Comment: Stay calm. I know you "just want to do this simple thing", but you should know what is happening in the big picture. I won't tell you exactly what you have to do because you are the one who should know this. Go check that Trailhead module I have linked in my answer. I'm not doing your homework for you.

Comment: thank you again. I'm attempting to use the Future functionality in the class. I updated my OP to show it. But I'm getting an error in reference to the Future line : "Unexpected Token '@'". Do have any ideas on that ? Also - should the InvocableMethod functionality be removed from the class ? It was in there when I was originally attempting to invoke the class with Process Builder, but that is apparently not going to be possible since I can't have an update before the callout...?